# Why my android application does not honor its style when deployed on actual device?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written an application for android API 14. When I am trying to run this app on emulator using **Galaxy Nexus API 22**, it shows fine, with all the colors and styles that I have programmed for. This is the screenshot:

[image]

But when I try to run it on my **Asus Fonpad 7** that runs Android 5, it seems that non of my styles are honored. The application uses the default UI. Screenshot is as follows:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? Please do let me know if any code snippets are required, since I am new to Android.

**Notes:**

- Images are scaled down.
- I am using Android Studio 1.2.2

**Codes:**

*main_activity.xml*

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:padding="12dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:baselineAligned="false"
     android:background="@color/kh_background">
 
     <Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:text="@string/btn_shopping_details"
         android:background="#ff02d0cb"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
     <Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:text="@string/btn_shopping_items"
         android:background="@color/kh_button_primary"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
     <Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:text="@string/btn_users"
         android:background="@color/kh_button_primary"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
     <Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:text="@string/btn_reports"
         android:background="@color/kh_button_primary"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

*style.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <style name="AppOrangeBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/kharidariActionBar</item>
         <!-- Support library compatibility -->
         <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/kharidariActionBar</item>
 
     </style>
     <!-- Style for the app's action bar -->
     <style name="kharidariActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
         <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
         <!-- Support library compatibility -->
         <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
     </style>
 </resources>
```

*values/colors.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <color name="kh_orange">#ffec704f</color>
     <color name="kh_background">#ff474b66</color>
     <color name="kh_button_primary">#ff02d0cb</color>
 </resources>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
 package com.baktash93.kharidari;
 
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 
 
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }
 
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
         return true;
     }
 
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
         int id = item.getItemId();
 
         //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
             return true;
         }
 
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
 }
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.baktash93.kharidari" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_kharidari"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppOrangeBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Update:**

I installed the same application on **Asus Fonpad 7** with **Android 4.4.3** and **Galaxy S3** with **Android 4.3** and one both it was showing fine, with all the layouts customized. Any idea now?

Comment: Could you please upload your activity layout XML file as a gist in github or something like that? Without the layout file I can't help you.

Comment: @Ybrin I have added the code here.

Comment: Are you sure you set the correct layout file in the Activity? bcz the code looks just fine to me

Comment: post your **Activity** which is using this **Layout**  here and also try running this app on some other device

Comment: The code looks fine. The problem is something with the colors. Where do you save the colors.xml?

Comment: @mushahid added the activity

Comment: @Ybrin added the colors.xml file

Comment: You can try making new values-v21 folder and put style.xml in it, but that's a lame approach share you manifest code as well where this activity is declared and did you try it on another device?

Comment: Try to run your app in an emulator with the same API Version as your Asus Fonpad 7 because for me all your code looks fine. Try the emulator and if it has the same problem, I will give your code another look.

Comment: your code looks fine to me,  Did you try to run it on any other device? i'm going to answer one solution but it will require you to change your style.xml to its default settings, i think your problem lies in style.xml

Answer (score 0):

try changing the style.xml to its default values given below, I guess your problem may be in the custom `@drawables/resource_values` you are using in style.xml

```
<resources>
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
</resource
```

Comment: If I use this code, then Android Studio will not recognize my custom theme that I coded for the same

Comment: yes give it a try and check if your app show similar results on both emulator and your Asus pad